# "For" loops increment not working correctly. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, loops, floating-point

```
for (float i = -1; i <= 1; i+=0.1f)   
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);   
}
```

This is results

```
-1
-0.9
-0.8
-0.6999999
-0.5999999
-0.4999999
-0.3999999
-0.2999999
-0.1999999
-0.09999993
7.450581E-08
0.1000001
0.2000001
0.3000001
0.4000001
0.5000001
0.6000001
0.7000001
0.8000001
0.9000002
```

Comment: Welcome to the war-stricken world of floating points.

Comment: A Frequently Asked Question, though usually in the form "float is broken!". Floats (or doubles) are not exact, try `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3`, it's false!

Comment: Well, actually, it is working exactly as it is supposed to.

Comment: You could loop through integers from -10 to 10 with increment 1 and divide by 10 inside the loop (casting integer to float) to make it work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating point inaccuracy examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a float is not an exact decimal number but a floating point number. Use decimal instead.

See wikipedia for reference: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)

Comment: Of course once he wants to increment by 1/3 he'll have the same problem even with `Decimal`

Answer (score 2):

Float and double are not able to display decimal values exactly. Have a look at wikipedia how they're implemented.

You may want to use `Decimal` instead.

Comment: `Decimal` ***also*** isn't "exact" - but it uses a different approximation approach that is more familiar to humans. But both are just as "exact" (or not)

Answer (score 2):

You need to read this:

[What Every Computer Scientist Needs To Know About Floating Point Numbers](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use integer numbers for indexing purposes. And if you need float values inside the loop, calculate it there:

```
for (int i = -10; i <= 10; i++)   
{
    Console.WriteLine(i / (float) 10);   
}
```

Comment: It works well, but can anyone explain how this works?

Comment: @JunedKhanMomin for each integer from -10 to 10 inclusive, divide it by floating point number 10. Result of this division (of an integer number by floating point number) is a floating point number, which is printed out to the console. Using integers in indexes releases yourself from dealing with floating point numbers rounding.

Answer (score 0):

`float` represents a 32-bit [floating point number](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). It cannot accurately represent these  values. Here is another, must-read-article, about floating point specifically for .NET: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx

Comment: -1: What do you mean, "it cannot accurately represent such *small* values"? If it cannot represent -0.7, isn't it pretty useless?

Comment: @ANeves, float cannot represent -0.7 exactly (Please read one of the linked articles). And no, it is not useless, because it allows us to make calculations, that are "accurate enough" for many scenarious, and do them fast. If one uses floating point, one should decide what accuracy is needed on the calculations. If exact accuracy is needed, one might use a fixed point type such as `decimal`, though it is larger (128 bits) and allows for a smaller range of values.

Comment: @driis with the links it is now a good answer; but it's been too long, so I cannot un-downvote it. I need to learn to wait the 5 minutes out before voting. :|

Comment: @driis `decimal` is no more "exact" than `float`/`double` (note I'm ignoring *precision* here - and focusing on *exact*) - simply; the approximation happens in base-10 space, where humans are more familiar with it.

Comment: @Marc, agreed. (I am not a native English speaker so I might have confused some terms).

Answer (score 0):

This is because of you're using floating points. Calculating of floating points is not totally correct, because your computer is using binary numbers internally and not decimal numbers. Good information about that problem are here: http://floating-point-gui.de/